# Akka + Kamon + StatsD + Grafana Setup

Tags: akka, graphite, grafana, statsd, kamon

We are having a research project on testing Akka for using in Automotive industries. So we need to measure performance. I decided to use Kamon+StatsD+Grafana, because is seems quite easy to run.

My probelm right now is, that i don't get the data from StatsD into Grafana. I tried also to generate a histogram as data manually without success:

```
Kamon.metrics.histogram("test-histogram").record(100)
```

When i create a new Datasource the only URL working is http://127.0.0.1:8000, regardless of what i did setup in application.conf. I also tried to use the Docker container IP as statsd.hostname without success.

Any ideas what i am missing here?

My setup is as followed:

**application.conf:**

```
    include "version"

    akka {

      loglevel = DEBUG

      extensions = ["kamon.statsd.StatsD",  "kamon.system.SystemMetrics", "kamon.logreporter.LogReporter"]

      actor {
        provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
      }
      remote {
        log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
        netty.tcp {
          //hostname = "132.199.59.153"
          //hostname = "169.254.137.212"
          hostname = "127.0.0.1"
          //hostname = "172.16.32.193"
          port = 2552
        }
      }

      cluster {
        seed-nodes = [
          //"akka.tcp://ActorSystem@132.199.59.153:2552",
          //"akka.tcp://ActorSystem@169.254.137.211:2552",
          "akka.tcp://ActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2552",
        ]
      }
    }


    kamon {
      metric {
        # Time interval for collecting all metrics and send the snapshots to all subscribed actors.
        tick-interval = 1 second

        # Specify if entities that do not match any include/exclude filter should be tracked.
        track-unmatched-entities = yes

        filters {
          akka-actor {
            includes = [ "**" ]
            excludes = [ ]
          }
          akka-dispatcher {
            includes = [ "**" ]
            excludes = [ ]
          }
          trace {
            includes = [ "**" ]
            excludes = [ ]
          }
        }
      }

      statsd {
        hostname = "172.17.0.2"
        port = 8125

        flush-interval = 10 seconds
        max-packet-size = 1024 bytes

        includes {
          akka-actor      = [ "**" ]
          akka-dispatcher = [ "**" ]
          trace           = [ "**" ]
        }

        simple-metric-key-generator {
          # Application prefix for all metrics pushed to StatsD. The default namespacing scheme for metrics follows
          # this pattern:
          #    application.host.entity.entity-name.metric-name
          application = "introduce-kamon-io"
        }
      }

      modules {
        kamon-statsd.auto-start = yes
        kamon-akka.auto-start = yes
        kamon-log-reporter.auto-start = yes
        kamon-system-metrics.auto-start = yes
      }
    }





# Disable legacy metrics in akka-cluster.
//akka.cluster.metrics.enabled=off

# Enable metrics extension in akka-cluster-metrics.
//akka.extensions=["akka.cluster.metrics.ClusterMetricsExtension"]

# Sigar native library extract location during tests.
# Note: use per-jvm-instance folder when running multiple jvm on one host.
//akka.cluster.metrics.native-library-extract-folder=${user.dir}/target/native
```

**build.sbt:**

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj._

name := "VideoProxy"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

val akkaVersion = "2.4.16"
val kamonVersion = "0.6.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.bytedeco" % "javacv-platform" % "1.3.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-sharding" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-tools" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % akkaVersion,
  "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.8.1",
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-core" % kamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-statsd" % kamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-akka-2.4" % kamonVersion exclude("io.kamon", "kamon-akka_akka-2.4_2.12"),
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-akka-remote-2.4" % kamonVersion exclude("io.kamon", "kamon-akka-remote_akka-2.4_2.12"),
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-log-reporter" % kamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-system-metrics" % kamonVersion
)


aspectjSettings

javaOptions <++= AspectjKeys.weaverOptions in Aspectj

// when you call "sbt run" aspectj weaving kicks in
fork in run := true
```